# When input new value is passed it does not affect #np and #total_amount automatically until I refresh the web page

Tags: javascript

When I change input value (id=input") after selecting option (change from string to value) it does not refresh automatically in #np and #total_amount

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("work").value;
  console.log(x);
  if (document.getElementById("work").value == "article") {
    var w = 5;
    if (document.getElementById("input")) {
      // renamed x to z 
      var z = document.getElementById("input").value;
      var wc = w * z;
      // not .value but .textContent 
      document.getElementById("total_amount").textContent = +wc;
      document.getElementById("np").textContent = +wc;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="number" value="0" id="input" name="word_count" value="500" style="text-align: center;" />
  <select id="work" onchange="myFunction();" name="work">
    <option disabled selected> -Select - </option>
    <option value="article">Article
    </option>
  </select>
</div> Total amount:
<span id="total_amount">
 </span> <br /> NP: <span id="np">
 </span>
```

I did like to see the results in #np and #total_amount change when I pass a new value to input after selecting from option

Answer (score 1):

You have an event handler assigned to the `<select>` element, but not to the `<input>` element. So when the input value is changed, your function isn't getting called and your "total_amount" and "np" values aren't updated.

You need to attach an event handler to the `change` event of your `<input>` tag. I'm not exactly sure how or what you want to calculate, but here's an example of what I mean using your code (look at my added comments on the HTML section):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("work").value;
  console.log(x);
  if (document.getElementById("work").value == "article") {
    var w = 5;
    if (document.getElementById("input")) {
      var z = document.getElementById("input").value;
      var wc = w * z;
      document.getElementById("total_amount").textContent = +wc;
      document.getElementById("np").textContent = +wc;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- Added onchange attribute to next line so function gets called when value changes -->
  <!-- Also removed duplicate value attribute -->
  <input type="number" onchange="myFunction()" id="input" name="word_count" value="500" style="text-align: center;" />
  <select id="work" onchange="myFunction();" name="work">
    <option disabled selected> -Select - </option>
    <option value="article">Article
    </option>
  </select>
</div> Total amount:
<span id="total_amount">
 </span> <br /> NP: <span id="np">
 </span>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for that observation, now it's working